# $S^1$ is not simply connected.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

I am a beginner of algebraic topology. While proving the theorem that $S^n$ is simply connected for $n \geq 2$ I have found a lemma which states that

> > Let $X = U \cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open with $U \cap V$ is path-connected and non-empty. If $U$ and $V$ are simply connected then $X$ is simply connected.

Now let us come back to $S^1$. Let $x,y \in S^1$ be two distinct points. Then clearly $S^1= U \cup V$ where $U = S^1 \setminus \{x \}$ and $V = S^1 \setminus \{y \}$. Now it is easy to see that both of $U$ and $V$ are open and path-connected. If $U$ and $V$ were simply connected then $S^1$ becomes simply connected, a contradiction. Hence both of $U$ and $V$ are multiply connected. But I think both of $U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R$ is simply connected then we get a contradiction. What is wrong to my reasoning? I don't understand that. Can somebody please help me in this regard?

Thank you very much.

Look at the page here corollary 59.2 $:$

[image]

Comment: Your "lemma" omits the condition that $U\cap V$ must be simply connected.

Comment: The boxed statement is false. See the Seifert-van Kampen theorem for the correct version.

Comment: Look at page no. 369 of James Munkres' Topology.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: The connectedness of $U\cap V$ is sufficient; van Kampen gives $\pi_1(U\cup V)$ as an amalgamated free product of $\pi_1 U$ and $\pi_1 V$.

Comment: From the corollary: "...suppose $U\cap V$ is nonempty _and path connected_."

Comment: Oh! I have missed one thing. Here $U \cap V$ is not path-connected. Isn't it so?

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay. Guess what, the space got by removing two points from a circle is **not** connected.

Comment: I have already mentioned that. Look at my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemma does not apply to your example because $U\cap V=S^1\setminus\{x,y\}$ is not path-connected.  Indeed, if $A$ and $B$ denote the two open arcs of the circle from $x$ to $y$, then $A$ and $B$ are both open in $U\cap V$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=U\cap V$, showing that $U\cap V$ is not connected.

Comment: I have already understood it @Eric Wofsey. See my above comment.